# Related tags recommendation gone rogue?

Tags: discussion, related-tags

I took a screenshot as I'm not sure how long this tag page is going to last :-)

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pileofshite/info

[image]

I just don't understand how both php and wordpress have been suggested as related tags. Almost looks like a joke to me ;)

No offence taken here btw but I thought it was worth mentioning this.

Comment: seems accurate ...

Comment: The Stack Overflow question has been deleted now (only visible to 10K+ers).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because there is exactly one question in that tag, and it also has both of the other tags. Therefore, it establishes a relation between them.

[image: the one question in the pileofshite tag, prior to editing]

...I've removed the tag, BTW.

Comment: Makes sense. I didn't see the question when I clicked on that tag though :-/

Comment: https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: I suppose I was wrong in assuming that related tags were somehow suggested by a recommender. Is it just simply a list of commonly associated tags?

Comment: Yep! It's super handy when you're trying to figure out what a tag is about, or just research a topic in depth. For a more hand-crafted set of recommendations, the tag wiki will sometimes contain useful info, at least when someone saw fit to add it.

Comment: Why exactly is there a pileofshite tag....?

Comment: @journeymangeek must be from our short-lived Toilet Overflow beta.